# Is this a F++ project?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, project

I am supposed to get a Visual Studio project to run again after several years. Originally it was written in Fortran and later a small GUI was build around it. Now my job is to change that GUI-part.

Since I am new to Visual Studio and Fortran, I need to know what kind of language the project (see below) is written in. I know there are Fortran files ( f90, fi, fd, for) but what language is .ico .rc. 
It seems to be a F++-Project. **But What is F++?** 
**Is that similar to C++?**

[image]

Comment: `.ico` is an icon and `.rc` is a resource file, neither is likely to have any code

Comment: What indications do you have that "it seems to be a F++ project"?

Comment: What is F++, why it should be any F++ when you see yourself taht it is Fortran? Did you read the attached readme?

Comment: Does any F++ even exist?

Comment: I've never heard of a F++. Microsoft does have F#, but it has no relation to Fortran.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Intel Visual Fortran in Microsoft Visual Studio. That little icon says Fo (for Fortran).

.ico is an icon file
.rc is a resource compiler file

These are used when creating Windows applications with a graphical user interface.

.fi and .fd are include files - the latter is created automatically from the .rc file when you build the project.